# Using pymysql to upload csv to database

Tags: python, csv

I am using pymysql to upload a csv file into my database.

I am using the following code:

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pymysql
import codecs
import csv
import urllib2
import pymysql.cursors

# Get  Data
csvfile = csv.reader(codecs.iterdecode(file('match_urls-2016-03-04', 'utf-8'))

# Connect to the database

connection = pymysql.connect(host='host.com', user='', password='', db='', cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        sql = "INSERT INTO Urlup(URL) VALUES(%s)"
        next(csvfile, None)
        for line in csvfile:
            cursor.execute(sql, (line[0]))

finally:
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()
```

but I am getting the error "connection" invalid syntax and unsure what I am supposed to use or even if the script will work

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the query parameters as a tuple, the comma makes the difference:

```
cursor.execute(sql, (line[0], ))
#                       HERE^
```

And, you are missing the closing parenthesis:

```
csvfile = csv.reader(codecs.iterdecode(file('match_urls-2016-03-04', 'utf-8')))
#                                                                         HERE^
```

Comment: Thanks - stil getting invalid syntax on connection = pymysql.con

Comment: @emmaperkins could you please post the complete error traceback you see? Thanks.

Comment: all i get is the posted in my main queston

Comment: @emmaperkins thanks for the additional information, updated the answer. Hope that helps.